# Not able to install Spyder in the virtual environment on Anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

I was trying to install spyder in the virtual environment on anaconda, but ended up with this debugging error.

> **Executing transaction**: 
>   \ DEBUG menuinst_win32:**init**(199): Menu: name: 'Anaconda${PY_VER} ${PLATFORM}', prefix: 'C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow', env_name: 'tensorflow', mode: 'None', used_mode: 'user'
>   DEBUG menuinst_win32:create(323): Shortcut cmd is C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\pythonw.exe, args are ['C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\cwp.py', 'C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow', 'C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\pythonw.exe', 'C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\Scripts\spyder-script.py']
>   | DEBUG menuinst_win32:create(323): Shortcut cmd is C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\python.exe, args are ['C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\cwp.py', 'C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow', 'C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\python.exe', 'C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\Scripts\spyder-script.py', '--reset']

I have also tried to clear the debugging errors using 
**conda config --set quiet True** , but no use.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: you should not install Spyder with conda, there are sevral warnings about that in new version pop-up window. what is your motivation to install spyder in venv? are you developping a spyder extension? if that is not the case, most likely you do not need it

Comment: Thats not right. You should not use pip!  you should use conda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should activate your virtual environment and then type: conda install spyder.  That should install spyder for that particular virtual environment. If you used pip or pip3 you may have problems.